# What is the value of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{128}+...}}}}$?

Tags: nested-radicals

An interesting radical I came up with and I'd like to know your approach.

Each term is of the form: $\frac{2^{2^r}}{2^{2^{r}+2^{r-1}+...+2+1}} = \frac{1}{2^{2^{r-1}+...+2+1}}$

Comment: I think the pattern is in the difference of powers $0,1,3,7$ subtract from previous term we have a GP $1-0=1,3-1=2,7-3=4$

Comment: Hint:$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^1}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^3}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^7}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^{15}}+…}}}}}=\\
\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^{3-2}}+\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^{7-4}}+\frac{1}{16}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^{15-8}}+…}}}}}=\\
\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^{3-2}}+\frac{1}{1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^{7-4}}+\frac{1}{1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^{15-8}}+…}}}}}=\\
\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^1}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^3}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^7}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^{15}}+…}}}}}}=\\$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you multiply the expression by $1/\sqrt{2}$ and push it inside each successive radical, you get the second radical.  So you have $x = \sqrt{1+x/\sqrt{2}}.$  When you solve for $x$, you get $x=\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: are you sure that it converge to  $\to \sqrt 2$ ?

Comment: Much better way than I went about it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let the number be $x$. Then

\begin{align}
\sqrt{2}(x^2-1)&=x\\
16x^2-8\sqrt{2}x-16&=0\\
(4x-\sqrt{2})^2&=18\\
4x-\sqrt{2}&=\pm3\sqrt{2}\\
4x&=4\sqrt{2}\qquad (\text{as }x\text{ is positive})\\
x&=\sqrt{2}
\end{align}